# setOnClickListener not getting called in custom Listview extending BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclick, onitemclick

The *setOnClickListener* for the checkbox in my custom listview is never getting called. Below is my code - any pointers will help.

The *setOnCheckedChangeListener* is getting called, but *setOnClickListener* doesn't get called.

Following is my custom ListAdapter:

```
public class Listadapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static String TAG = "focus";
List<PackageInfo> packageList;
Activity context;
PackageManager packageManager;
private final boolean[] itemChecked;

List<String> appNamestoBlock_local;

public Listadapter(Activity context, List<PackageInfo> packageList,
        PackageManager packageManager, List<String> appNamestoBlock) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.packageList = packageList;
    this.packageManager = packageManager;
    this.appNamestoBlock_local = appNamestoBlock;

    itemChecked = new boolean[packageList.size()];
}

private String getSerializedBlockedAppNames() {
    String serializedBlockedAppNames;
    Log.v(TAG,
            "-------- List<String> list = "
                    + TextUtils.join(",", appNamestoBlock_local));
    serializedBlockedAppNames = TextUtils.join(",", appNamestoBlock_local);
    return serializedBlockedAppNames;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView apkName;
    CheckBox ck1;
}

public int getCount() {
    return packageList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return packageList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    Log.v(TAG + " Listadapter", "entered getView(...)");
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.ck1 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        //debug
        holder.ck1.setFocusable(false);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);

    Drawable appIcon = packageManager
            .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
    String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
            packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
    appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 40);
    holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
    holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
    holder.apkName.setText(appName);
    // holder.ck1.setChecked(false);

    if (itemChecked[position])
        holder.ck1.setChecked(true);
    else {
        holder.ck1.setChecked(false);
        Log.v(TAG, "setting Checkbox=false, in ListAdapter.java, line 108");
    }

    // Log.v(TAG,
    // "-------- checking in getView() in ListAdapter if appName is in getSerializedBlockedAppNames()");
    if (getSerializedBlockedAppNames().contains(appName)) {
        Log.v(TAG + " ListAdapter",
                "-------- YES, appName is in getSerializedBlockedAppNames(), appName = "
                        + appName);
        holder.ck1.setChecked(true);

    }

    holder.ck1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (isChecked) {
                Log.v(TAG + " Listadapter",
                        "isChecked=TRUE in Listadapter.java, item[position] = "
                                + String.valueOf(itemChecked[position]));
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG + " Listadapter",
                        "isChecked=FALSE in Listadapter.java, item[position] = "
                                + String.valueOf(itemChecked[position]));
            }

        }

    });

    holder.ck1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.v(TAG + " Listadapter",
                    "Entered holder.ck1.setOnClickListener ");
            if (holder.ck1.isChecked()) {
                itemChecked[position] = true;
                Log.v(TAG + " Listadapter",
                        "in ck1.onClick and setting itemChecked = TRUE");
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG + " Listadapter",
                        "in ck1.onClick and setting itemChecked = FALSE");
                itemChecked[position] = false;
            }

        }
    });

    return convertView;

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
holder.ck1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

   }
}
```